# How to reverse the order of a input file using C++?

Tags: c++, file, reverse, reversing

I need to reverse the order of the file and outputted into another file. For example, the

input:

```
hello
this is a testing file again
just    so    much  fun
```

Expected output:

```
just    so    much  fun
this is a testing file again 
hello
```

This is my current code, it printed to where it reverses the order of the lines but also the order of the characters of each word.

Current:

```
nuf  hcum    os    tsuj
 niaga elif gnitset a si siht
olleh

int print_rev(string filename, char c){
  ifstream inStream (filename);
  ofstream outStream;
  inStream.seekg(0,inStream.end);
  int size = inStream.tellg();
  outStream.open("output.txt");

  for (int j=1; j<=size; j++){ 
    inStream.seekg(-j, ios::end);
    c=inStream.get();
    outStream << c;
  }

  inStream.close();
  outStream.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean the expected output is "fun much so just again file testing a is this hello" ?

Comment: The question needs format editing to better show the line-by-line nature of the file contents

Comment: Why are `text` and `c` passed in to the function? One isn't used at all, and the other is better served just being a local.

Comment: What is your design? *How* did you expect your code to do what you wanted?

Comment: This code is meant to be a function that will be used by the main code

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813930/read-a-file-backwards may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You're reversing the whole file, character by character.  What you want to do is read in each line separately, and then reverse the line order.

A stack of lines seems like a good choice for this :

```
int printRev(string filename)
{
    stack<string> lines;
    ifstream in(filename);
    string line;
    while (getline(in, line))
    {
        lines.push(line);
    }
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    while (!lines.empty())
    {
        out << lines.top() << endl;
        lines.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```